# Can't put image inside tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have other tables working OK, but this one is not working. The image dont stay inside the cell (see the little lines):

[image]

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

The mode is Aspect to Fit, but ive tried everything and nothing seems to work.

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class PratosViewController:             UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

  var restauranteRow: PFObject!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var Scroller: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var tituloRestaurante: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var imagemRestaurante: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Scroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 400, 0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    tituloRestaurante.text = restauranteRow["nome"] as? String

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.Scroller.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.Scroller.contentSize.height = 400
    self.Scroller.contentSize.width = 0
}



//TableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ceculaPratos") as! PratosTableViewCell

    let imagem = restauranteRow["imagem1"] as! PFFile
    imagem.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            cell.imagemCelula.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

        }
    }



    return cell
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom cell and add autolayout constraints to satisfy the image dimension inside the cell

Comment: I added "missing constraints" and now it looks inside the cell, but its not the same size as storyboard.

Check:
Img1: http://i.imgur.com/FuatxKI.png
Img2: http://i.imgur.com/TwIdt5g.png

Comment: Try adding a constraint for the height

Comment: Same thing... All the others work, this tableview I can't do the same =/

Comment: have you implemented heightForRowAtIndexPath: tableview delegate method?

Comment: No, because im using storyboard and the size I draw in the storyboard should be the same after compile =/